# fileSystem does not work as before

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova

I used the code below to get the path to download, but once formatted and installed the mac version 3.3.0rc1 of the cordova, the code does not work as it should.

```
function onSuccess(fileSystem) {
    console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);
}

// request the persistent file system
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, null);
```

Before, the code returning something like:

```
/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/CF2A9018-49B9-4DE6-91FC-EA76CB435FC8/Document
```

Now, the code returns only:

```
"/"
```

And I can not download that way

Any change in the cordova? What code should I use to download?

I've tried several but did not succeed.

Thanks to all.

Comment: The file plugin has been updated, have a look at this link : http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2014/2/17/Cordova-File-System--Important-Update

Comment: Thanks man... Now everything is working.. :)